# Deep in the ocean, if an object moves quickly relative to the water does that affect the pressure on that object?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm no expert on fluids, but if say you were in submarine moving against a fast ocean current, would the pressure on the submarine's hull be different compared to just sitting there in calm waters at the same depth?

If so, what area of fluid dynamics would describe this phenomenon?

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you look into aerodynamics and the drag force.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the answer is yes and it is called Bernoulli's principle. I shall study it.